# Close DB connection with Neomodel

Tags: python, neo4j, neomodel

I'm using the [Neomodel](https://neomodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) lib and I can't find anything in the documentation to properly close the connection to the DB. Have I missed something or is there a way to access the underlying connection and close that?

When existing the python program an open connection will generate following errors:

```
Failed to write data to connection Address(host='localhost', port=7687) (Address(host='127.0.0.1', port=7687)); ("0; 'Underlying socket connection gone (_ssl.c:2263)'")

Failed to write data to connection Address(host='localhost', port=7687) (Address(host='127.0.0.1', port=7687)); ("0; 'Underlying socket connection gone (_ssl.c:2263)'")
```

Update: Found bug registered regarding this issue [Underlying socket connection gone? #474](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neomodel/issues/474)

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Neo4j with Docker and the latest version (3.5.11) and had the same issue. Downgrading to the 3.4.15 Docker image fixed this issue and a couple of other issues (broken pipe) for me, so seems like this is related to the Neo4j version in use?

Answer (score 0):

1/ Add **db** to your neomodel import
2/ Try this (Python) :

```
db.driver.close()
```